# How do I enable a proper fade transition to the body element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this document, there is the main document which, along with the body, and the title text, changes color with a fade effect (it should, at least) after a certain amount of time from an array of colors. However, the body element seems to change the gradient properly, but without playing the fade transition. I am entirely new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and am therefore unable to correct my code on my own. I would be very glad if you could correct my error. This code probably should not be considered well written.

Here is the html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" id="htmlMain">

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);

            function main(){
                var myVar;
                var colors = ['#B86B77', '#C0838C', '#CF989F', '#D8ABB1', '#E0BCBF'];
                head = document.getElementById('header');
                head.style.transition="all 2.5s";

                document.body.style.transition="all 2.5s";
                var i = 0;
                changeColor();

                function changeColor() {
                    myVar = setTimeout(change, 1000);
                }

                function change() {
                    // For Safari and similar browsers.
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i++];
                    // For heading
                    head.style.color = colors[colors.length - i];

                    var orientation = 'top'; // For now

                    // Body gradient
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-moz-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-ms-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-o-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';

                    if(head.style.color == document.body.style.backgroundColor)
                        head.style.color = '#9C626A';

                    if(i == colors.length) i = 0;
                    changeColor();
                }
            }
        </script>




        <title>Debjyoti Sikdar</title>

    </head>

    <body transition="all 2.5s";>
           <p style="text-align:center;"> <ubuntu_bold id="header">Debjyoti Sikdar</ubuntu_bold> </p>
           </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    transition: "all 2.5s";
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #70bg32; /* 70bg32 */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
    background: -o-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
    background: linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
}

ubuntu_bold
{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #9C626A;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with additional information if the provided answer cannot be accepted for any reason and specifically state why so we might best assist you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took what you had, removed some syntax issues (missing tags in HTML, some other stuff) and commented out some of the CSS and code.
I also changed the colors to make it painfully obvious what was happening.
I also added a longer delay since you had 1000 and had a 2.5s transition conflict.

I believe this is something you can compare your code to and build from.

I put this in a snippet so you can run it and see it here:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);

function main() {
  let myVar;
  // changed colors just to make it painfully obvious
  let colors = ['#B86B77', '#776BB8', '#CF989F', '#6BB877', '#6B77B8'];
  let head = document.getElementById('header');
  head.style.transition = "all 2.5s";
  document.body.style.transition = "all 2.5s";
  let i = 0;
  let timerTime = 10000;
  changeColor();
  

  function changeColor(delay) {
    myVar = setTimeout(change, delay);
  }

  function change() {
  console.log("i:",i,"Color:", colors[i] );
    // For Safari and similar browsers.
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i++];
    // For heading
    head.style.color = colors[colors.length - i];
    var orientation = 'top'; // For now
    // Body gradient
/* just use linear-gradient which is supported pretty well re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()
document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-moz-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-ms-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '-o-linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
    */
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(' + orientation + ', ' + colors[i] + ', ' + colors[colors.length - i] + ')';
   // if (head.style.color == document.body.style.backgroundColor)
  //    head.style.color = '#9C626A';
    if (i == colors.length) i = 0;
    changeColor(timerTime);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  transition: "all 2.5s";
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: #70bg32;
  /* 70bg32 */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 /* commented out to the script does this
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
  background: linear-gradient( to left top, #B86B77, #E0BCBF);
  */
}

ubuntu_bold {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #9C626A;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" id="htmlMain">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Debjyoti Sikdar</title>
</head>

<body transition="all 2.5s">
  <div>
    <p style="text-align:center;">
      <ubuntu_bold id="header">Debjyoti Sikdar</ubuntu_bold>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```